# Package fontspec Error: The Font SimSun can't be found

Tags: latex, cjk, overleaf, fontspec

I am using Overleaf for my Chinese thesis work and having this issue "Package fontspec Error: The font "SimSun" cannot be found."

```
\setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold = {2.25},ItalicFont={[simkai.ttf]}]{SimSun}
```

` I am using XELateX Compiler. How I can solve this..

Because of this only Chinese Characters are not printing on my files.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of the CJK Chinese fonts which are available on overleaf from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese

```
AR PL KaitiM Big5
AR PL KaitiM GB
AR PL Mingti2L Big5
AR PL SungtiL GB
AR PL UKai CN
AR PL UKai HK
AR PL UKai TW
AR PL UKai TW MBE
AR PL UMing CN
AR PL UMing HK
AR PL UMing TW
AR PL UMing TW MBE
BabelStone Han
Droid Sans Fallback
FandolFang
FandolHei
FandolKai
FandolSong
HanaMinA
Noto Sans CJK HK
Noto Sans CJK SC
Noto Sans CJK TC
Noto Sans Mono CJK HK
Noto Sans Mono CJK SC
Noto Sans Mono CJK TC
Noto Serif CJK SC
Noto Serif CJK TC
UKIJ CJK
WenQuanYi Micro Hei
WenQuanYi Micro Hei Mono
WenQuanYi Zen Hei
WenQuanYi Zen Hei Mono
WenQuanYi Zen Hei Sharp
cwTeXFangSong
cwTeXHeiBold
cwTeXKai
cwTeXMing
cwTeXYen
TW-Kai
TW-Sung
```

Use one of these fonts for your document or compile your document on a computer which has SimSun installed

Comment: when i use this syntax \setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold = {2.25},ItalicFont={simkai.ttf}]{SimSun.ttc} the error is solve.